# glyphicon bootstrap icon-car doesn't work for me

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with glyphicon bootstrap icons, some of them are working good
some others not , i need that particular one icon-car

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>index"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>voitures-et-automobiles/liste/"><span class="glyphicon icon-car"></span> Voitures</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>a/b/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Pieces Auto</a></li>

        <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>test/test1/test2/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>q/c/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span> test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo URL; ?>magazine/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> blog</a></li>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

icon-car is not a glyphicon that comes with Bootstrap by default. You can find the entire list here : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Comment: what about these ones here http://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/  i see there icon-car

Comment: This is an add on and not part of bootstrap, you'll need to add a few more files to your code and also a bit of configuration as described here : https://github.com/marcoceppi/bootstrap-glyphicons

Comment: No worries, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I am new at stackoverflow i dont know how to  close the question or to vote !! i cliked the up sign to increase the vote it seems its not counting since i am new

Comment: You can click the green arrow just below the number